# Is free / wild camping legal or tolerated on Kinmen and Matsu islands?

Tags: budget, legal, camping, taiwan, islands

Matsu island of Taiwan (but actually located just near Fuzhou, China) is beautiful and sparsely populated. Official tourist accommodations are expensive compared to PRC and even a little high compared to Taiwan perhaps.

It seems like a gorgeous place to camp wild. But I can't seem to find anywhere if you might get in trouble for doing so outside an official campground. In fact I can't even find info regarding whether there are official campgrounds.

I'd assume the answer for Matsu would be the same for Kinmen (Quemoy) since they are often mentioned together though not actually so close to each other as I just found out.

Comment: So far I have not found it difficult on the "mainland" of Taiwan. Just most nights are very hot in the tent due to lack of any breeze. Finding a place to wash more than hands and face is very difficult. Many parks have too many territorial stray dogs!

Comment: Cool. Penghu is a major tourist attraction, which often makes free camping a no-no in various places. The other two islands are lesser destinations. Another difference though could be military presence. I don't know how prominent the military are in Penghu but Matsu is crawling with them and their hidey places and I'm pretty sure Kinmen is too. This could be a second reason to not want free campers - they can look like spies snooping around sensitive areas...

Comment: Kinmen also has lots of military presence (it is mostly military and Chinese mainland shoppers on daily trips - it is 30m ferry ride from Xiamen). Lots of open space there though

Comment: I think this is better suited for The Great Outdoors SE: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camping

Comment: @GeorgeSapkin: Does Outdoors embrace questions about specific locations around the world or have some contributors with known Taiwan expertise?

Comment: Did you end up finding out?

Comment: @JonathanReez: No I didn't. I had trouble booking the ferry in my final week in Taipei as the more economical ones only run a couple of times a week and when I was going to just book the more expensive one the weather turned bad and all ferries were cancelled. As my visa was then running out I flew directly to mainland China and missed the islands )-:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one took more than a bit of research and emails (and google translate).

Taiwan oversees both, these strings of islands, are administered separately, Kinmen/Jīnmén 金門 by Kinmen County, Matsu/Mǎzǔ 馬祖 by Lienchaing County.

The answer is, yes, you can free camp on both Kinman and Matsu but that is a qualified 'yes,' as you shouldn't in any area with is military presence (so, it goes without saying: don't pitch your tent, or fire up the barbie there).

Wild camping is legal in Taiwan. Also known as free camping, you find a spot to set down your gear and stay, overnight or longer. Camping is hugely popular in Taiwan, and campsites, of all descriptions and prices, abound.

> [Taiwan is currently experiencing a “golden age” of camping](http://topics.amcham.com.tw/2016/07/your-home-away-from-home/), according to Morio Chen, honorary president of the Formosa Camping and Caravanning Club (FCCC). Every weekend, upwards of 300,000 people head for the hills and down to the beaches to set up their tents in order to hike, climb, river trace, surf, cycle, and visit hot springs.

For a quick, on-the-road reference, Wikitravel lists very affordable inns, guest houses, and homestays on both [Kinmen](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kinmen) and [Matsu](http://wikitravel.org/en/Matsu). Matsu National Scenic Area [backpacking brochure](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0QgFptQVvTMeEt0WWF4MkkySmc) is a handy take-along.

And a solid [Wikitravel overview](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Taiwan):

> Informal camping is very easy and safe in Taiwan. Occasionally you can be scolded for choosing a bad spot, but threatening or violent behaviour is unheard of. It is generally okay to pitch a tent on the grounds of public schools, even in some larger towns. Just make sure to be gone before children arrive in the morning, and if there's a night guard posted, ask for permission first. Temple custodians may be willing to let you camp on their grounds or terraces as well, and you're unlikely to have any trouble camping next to an unstaffed shrine (certain ones may be considered undesirable because of evil spirits, but any objections will stem from concern for your well-being, not anger). Empty lots are of course fair game as well.
>
> In national parks, there may be a rule against pitching tents outside of designated camping areas (which may or may not be present, and sometimes have a fee). However, it is considered normal to camp in parking areas or lawns anyway once the staff have gone home for the night. But do note that starting fires outside of designated fire pits is generally not considered appropriate in Taiwan (except on some beaches), and you should respect this. Taiwanese mountaineers cook and boil water using tiny portable gas stoves, which you can buy at outdoor sporting supply stores in major cities.

**Edit**: Also reference the WikiVoyage summaries for [Matsu](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Matsu) and [Kinmen](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kinmen), with a thank you to @davidvc for the recommendation.

**Addenda:**

An email reply from the Matsu National Scenic Area Administration, Tourism Bureau, MOTC, shares this:

> There are two camping sites running by local companies on Nangan island:
>
> 1. Camping site at Mazu Religious Culture Park: providing bathrooms with shower facilities. Please contact Longfu Company( 0836-55661) for more information.
> 2. Camping site at No.55 Hostel : providing power and bathrooms with shower facilities. Please contact No.55 Hostel via phone (0836-26426) or email (no55hostel@gmail.com) or searching on this website: http://bnb.matsu.idv.tw/No.55Hostel.
>
> As for the campsite rules, please inquire managers from each site. However, please always be alert to snakes from April to September while camping in Matsu.
>
> We wish you a pleasant journey in Matsu.

Comment: +1, great answer, but please consider linking to wikivoyage instead of wikitravel: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/881/wikitravel-vs-wikivoyage-whats-going-to-be-the-difference